# Don't want to manually copy android JNI(.so) and Jar libraries to App project each time

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm building and Eclipse to make an Android library I want to distribute to developers.

TedLibJni:
It uses the Android NDK and so it compiles down to a .so file.

TedLibJar:
It also has a Java interface that binds the then extern'd calls in the JNI, so it has a Jar library associated with it.

TedDroidApp:
The concensus is that I need to manually copy both TedLibJni.so and TedLibJar.jar to lib/armeabi of this App for it to be used.

Question: **Is there any way that TedDroidApp can pick up the externally located .so or .jar files? It seems crazy that I would have to manually copy and paste these files accross each time I iterate them.**

Answer (score 0):

Use an Android library project for the JNI code and the JAR. You can then attach the Android library project to other projects. With the new Gradle-based build system, you can package the library project up as an AAR and obtain it from an artifact repository as well.

[CWAC-AndDown](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-anddown), my wrapper around the C `hoedown` library, works this way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is gradle a requirement for your project to build? Because the anddown project creates a anddown.jar but when it runs, it fails to load the anddown.so via the line: System.loadLibrary("anddown"); likely because its not including the jni.